# Strange Behaviour with Date Object with Mongodb producing invalid string [UTC]

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, datetime, quarkus-panache

I am stuck between a strange behavior of java.util.Date object. I am using mongodb and all dates are stored in UTC. While the stored value in the database is all correct.

> "dateCreated" : ISODate("2021-05-08T15:37:48.882Z")

But when it is mapped to Pojo property of type java.util.Date the output is

> "dateCreated":"2021-05-08T15:37:48.882Z[UTC]"

and there is  this **[UTC]** which I do not understand why? Has someone caught up with this issue ?
I am using `quarkus` with `jdk11` and the library for `mongo` connectivity is `io.quarkus:quarkus-mongodb-panache`

**EDIT:**

To process the information in my android app I have created a custom deserializer:

```
class DateDeserializer(vc: Class<*>?) : StdDeserializer<Date>(vc) {

    constructor() : this(Date::class.java)

    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser?, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): Date {
//        TODO("Not yet implemented")
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Date.from(ZonedDateTime.parse(p?.text).toInstant())
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
        }
    }

}
```

But as I said, does not seem to be a cleaner approach.

Let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening with

```
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jsonb'
```

being present with was serializing the timestamped date obtained from driver to the mentioned format, removed that dependency and everything works.

Thanks to all those who spent time thinking about the solution.